# XLPagerTabStrip - How do I change the selected bar color as the selection changes

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I'm trying to do a design a [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) control where the overall theme changes as the tabs change.

The following is what's getting called when a tab changes

```
changeCurrentIndexProgressive = { [weak self] (oldCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, newCell: ButtonBarViewCell?, progressPercentage: CGFloat, changeCurrentIndex: Bool, animated: Bool) -> Void in
        guard changeCurrentIndex == true else { return }
        oldCell?.label.textColor = .black
        newCell?.label.textColor = UIColor.red

        //Change the navigation bar's color
        self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red

        //Attempting to change the selected bar color
        self?.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.green       
   }
```

Changing the navigation controllers color works, but I can't get the the selected bar (or any thing under the settings object) to change from within here?

Is it possible to change the settings once the view has been loaded?

Comment: Consider adding more tags to your question. There are 0 followers on `xlpagertabstrip`

Comment: Thanks for adding those.  I thought since they linked on their github to post questions here with that tag, that they were following it..

Comment: Hmm. Maybe, but still, only ~23 questions on this whole site have that tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Code Check**

if you check the code [Code Search for selectedBarBackgroundColor](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/search?q=selectedBarBackgroundColor&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) then you find this 3 interesting search results:

[BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController#viewDidLoad](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/blob/d12b4fa6c51f091deb06dd4ba9eaec66d6102fbb/Sources/BaseButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController.swift#L88)

```
buttonBarView.selectedBar.backgroundColor = settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor
```

[BarPagerTabStripViewController#viewDidLoad](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/blob/d12b4fa6c51f091deb06dd4ba9eaec66d6102fbb/Sources/BarPagerTabStripViewController.swift#L68)

```
barView.selectedBar.backgroundColor = settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor ?? barView.selectedBar.backgroundColor
```

[ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController#viewDidLoad](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/blob/d12b4fa6c51f091deb06dd4ba9eaec66d6102fbb/Sources/ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController.swift#L141)

```
buttonBarView.selectedBar.backgroundColor = settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor
```

that means that you need to set the BackgroundColor before an viewDidLoad.

**Issue**

see also the answer of this issue: [XLPagerTabStrip Issue #137](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/137):

> Actually this isnot a issue. Settings should be configured before viewDidLoad is called. Could you please document it in the readme?

**workaround**

`buttonBarView` is a public var maybe you can set it additional to the settings direct this property: `buttonBarView.selectedBar.backgroundColor`

Comment: Thank you, I must have missed that thread since I tried looking through the github issues.  Works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: This should be written in the documentation. Please, Xmartlabs, could you update your docs ? Thanks.

Comment: @Fox5150 you should open an issue at the github repo for this